# Что объединяет существительные ГРИФ, ЖУРАВЛЬ, НОРКА

Tags: общие-вопросы

Ребенок участвовал в олимпиаде.Там был такой вопрос:
Докажите, что объединяет существительные ГРИФ, ЖУРАВЛЬ, НОРКА.
Стало очень интересно и мне.

Comment: А для какого класса задача?

Comment: Олимпиада по русскому языку 1-3 класс

Answer (score 8):

На вскидку их объединяет то, что все эти слова могут обозначать как одушевлённый, так и неодушевлённый предмет: гриф - это птица и пластина, стержень; журавль - птица и приспособление для доставание воды из колодца;  норка - млекопитающее и маленькая нора.

Comment: Спасибо. Но мне кажется, что здесь есть еще варианты, т.к. олимпиада по русскому языку.
1) во всех словах есть буква Р
2)все слова не среднего рода
Возможно есть что-то еще?

Comment: @Светлана73, с буквой Р не подходит, так как тут указано, что надо выделить общее в существительных, а это предполагает, что речь пойдёт не о составе слов, а о грамматике (одушевлённость/неодушевлённость - это грамматическая категория). А  НЕ чем-то является всё что угодно (например, все эти слова не в творительном падеже), что делает вопрос бессмысленным.  Если б олимпиада была по биологии, то всё это организмы из царства животных.

Ещё у всех слов представленный вид совпадает с начальной формой, но подобный правильный ответ был бы совсем странным.

Comment: Еще могу добавить, что начинаются слова с согласной. Хотя вряд ли это правильный ответ. 
   Нравится ответ Марк Иза, но не уверена, что ученики 1-3 кл знают 2-ое значение слова ГРИФ

Comment: >знают 2-ое значение слова ГРИФ  
  
Да они и первое могут не знать.
Но трудно предположить, что тут что-то иное, типа банальной игры с буквами.

Answer (score 0):

Их обединяет тема "Омонимы". Если это изучалось.

Comment: Спасибо. Нет, эта тема не изучалась.